# Remembering jquery toggle across site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to hide and unhide a lengthy menu with a button click, and that I have been able to do.  But I don't want visitors to have to hide the menu every time they visit a new page, so I would like their last click to be remembered.  This I have not been able to do. Any help is appreciated. I am even open to a better way to do this.

The code I thought would work, but doesn't, is:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div.themenu").toggle(100);
    });
});

$(function(){
       if($.cookie){
           $("#themenu").toggle(!(!!$.cookie("toggle-state")) || $.cookie("toggle-state") === 'true');
    }
    $('#menubutton').on('click', function(){
        $("#themenu").toggle();
        $.cookie("toggle-state", $("#themenu").is(':visible'), {expires: 1, path:'/'}); 
});
});
```

The code for the button they click is:

```
<button id="menubutton" class="myButton">Show / Hide Menu</button>
```

And the long, long menu is shown like this:

```
<div class="themenu">Long Long Menu Code</div>
```

Comment: Check your selectors: `$("X")` selects all elements of type X, `$("#X")` selects the element with id X, `$(".X")` selects all elements of class X.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: here's an alternative solution which doesn't require a cookie, but sets a URL parameter:

```
//on page load
if (location.href.match('menu=show'))
  $("#themenu").toggle();

//for every link click, block & redirect with menu=show if menu is visible
$(document.body).on('mousedown', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var menuParam = (location.href.match('?') ? '&' : '?') + 'menu=show';
  location.href = $("#themenu").is(':visible') ? this.href + menuParam: this.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is a good place to store this kind of state. Setting is as easy as `localStorage.menu = 'hidden'` or `localStorage.menu = 'visible'`, checking can be done with `(localStorage && localStorage.menu==='hidden')`. People with REALLY old browsers won't get the feature but that's a very small slice of users. This setting will live across visits to the site but only in the same browser. There is an issue with some browsers in 'private browsing' mode. They sometimes make localStorage cause an error when modified.